# From the equation $\sigma(x^{\sigma(y)-1})=\frac{1}{\varphi(x)}(x^{y+1}-1)$ involving arithmetic functions to a characterization of Mersenne exponents

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, totient-function, divisor-sum

In this post we denote the Euler's totient function that counts the number of positive integers $1\leq k\leq n$ such that $\gcd(k,n)=1$ as $\varphi(n)$, and the sum of divisors function $\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}d$ as $\sigma(n)$. As reference I add the Wikipedia [*Mersenne prime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime)) that refers the well-known definition that a prime $p$ is a Mersenne exponent if $2^p-1$ is prime. This prime constellation corresponds to the entry *A000043* from the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

From previous definition and the calculations of previous arithmetic function $\varphi(n)$ and $\sigma(n)$ it is easy to check the proof of the following claim.

**Claim.** *If* $x=p$ *is* *(a prime)* *such that* $y=2^p-1$ *is* *(also)* *prime, then* $(x,y)$ *solves the equation* $$\sigma(x^{\sigma(y)-1})=\frac{1}{\varphi(x)}(x^{y+1}-1).\tag{1}$$

We propose the following conjecture inspired in previous claim, from the substitution $$y=2\cdot 2^{\varphi(x)}-1=2^{1+\varphi(x)}-1.\tag{2}$$

**Conjecture.** *Let* $x\geq 1$ *be an integer that satisfies* 
$$\sigma(x^{\sigma(2^{1+\varphi(x)}-1)-1})=\frac{1}{\varphi(x)}(x^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}-1),\tag{3}$$

*then* $x$ *is a Mersenne exponent.*

> **Question.** What work can be done with the purpose to prove or refute previous **Conjecture**? **Many thanks.**

**Computational evidence.**  You can check in the web *Sage Cell Server* this line written in Pari/GP

`for(x=1,16,if(sigma(x^(sigma(2*2^(eulerphi(x))-1 )-1))==(x^(2*2^(eulerphi(x))-1 +1)-1)/eulerphi(x) ,print(x)))`

just copy and paste it to evaluate in the web choosing as Language the option *GP*.

Comment: One can to show that $x=\prod_{1\leq k\leq n}p_k$ has no repeated prime factors (using the same reasoning that the answer of the recent post MSE **3578715**), thus $n=\omega(x)$ is the number of distinct prime  factors $p_k$ dividing $x$. And (also from the reference) if there aren't typos $$\prod_{k=1}^{\omega(x)}(p_k^{\sigma(2\cdot 2^{\varphi(x)}-1)}-1)=-1+\prod_{k=1}^{\omega(x)}p_k^{\,2\cdot 2^{\varphi(x)}}.$$
I would like to know if it is possible to prove the **Conjecture** or to find a counterexample.

Comment: Of course if you want to **denote** $x=M$ or $x=E$ feel free to do it in your answer. On the other hand is very welcome if some person can to test our conjecture for a segment of integers greater than my **Computational evidence**. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conjecture is true.

*Proof* :

$x=1$ does not satisfy $(3)$, and $x=2$ satisfies $(3)$. In the following, $x\ge 3$.

As you already noticed, $x$ has to be a square-free integer.

Then, letting $x=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}p_k$ with $n=\omega(x)$, we get

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\bigg({p_k}^{\sigma(2^{1+\varphi(x)}-1)}-1\bigg)=-1+\prod_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}$$

Suppose here that $2^{1+\varphi(x)}-1$ is a composite number.

Here, using the following facts :

- If $N$ is a composite number, then $\sigma(N)\ge 1+\sqrt N+N$.
- If $N\ge 3$, then $\varphi(N)\ge 2$.
- If $m\ge 2$ and $y\gt 0$, then $m^{2+y}-1\ge m^{1+y}$.

we get

$$\begin{align}-1&=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\bigg({p_k}^{\sigma(2^{1+\varphi(x)}-1)}-1\bigg)-\prod_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}
\\\\&\ge \prod_{k=1}^{n}\bigg({p_k}^{1+\sqrt{2^{1+\varphi(x)}-1}+2^{1+\varphi(x)}-1}-1\bigg)-\prod_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}
\\\\&=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\bigg({p_k}^{\sqrt{2^{1+\varphi(x)}-1}+2^{1+\varphi(x)}}-1\bigg)-\prod_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}
\\\\&\ge\prod_{k=1}^{n}\bigg({p_k}^{\sqrt{2^{1+2}-1}+2^{1+\varphi(x)}}-1\bigg)-\prod_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}
\\\\&\ge\prod_{k=1}^{n}\bigg({p_k}^{2+2^{1+\varphi(x)}}-1\bigg)-\prod_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}
\\\\&\ge\prod_{k=1}^{n}\bigg({p_k}^{1+2^{1+\varphi(x)}}\bigg)-\prod_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}\end{align}$$
from which we have
$$-1\ge \prod_{k=1}^{n}\bigg({p_k}^{1+2^{1+\varphi(x)}}\bigg)-\prod_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}$$
which is impossible since the RHS is positive.

So, we see that $2^{1+\varphi(x)}-1$ is a prime number.

Then, we get
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\bigg({p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}-1\bigg)=-1+\prod_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}$$

Suppose here that $n\ge 2$. Then, we get
$$\begin{align}1&=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\bigg({p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}\bigg)-\prod_{k=1}^{n}\bigg({p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}-1\bigg)
\\\\&\ge {p_n}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\bigg({p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}\bigg)-\bigg({p_n}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}-1\bigg)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\bigg({p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}\bigg)
\\\\&=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\bigg({p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}\bigg)\end{align}$$
from which we have
$$1\ge \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\bigg({p_k}^{2^{1+\varphi(x)}}\bigg)$$
which is impossible since the RHS is larger than $1$.

So, we have to have $\omega(x)=n=1$, and $x$ has to be a prime number.

Therefore, $x$ has to be a Mersenne exponent. $\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: Many thanks I am going to read it again, and study i in next days, but I would like to say that this seems to me as a little miracle. I would to emphasize that this is now your proposition as a characterization of Mersenne exponents, many thanks again for such nice proof and sharing your calculations.